# display the index for which data is owned by the user who logged in

Tags: yii2

how to display user data is logged in the index , while other user data does not appear , only users who log you appear

**n2 should only user data that appears**

[image]

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    $searchModel = new CreateBookingsSearch();
    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);
    $model = new Kasbon();
    $data = Kasbon::findOne($id);

    return $this->render('index', [
        'searchModel' => $searchModel,
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'model' => $model,
        'data' => $data,
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your *Search model*, add a filter in the `search` function:

```
$query->andFilterWhere(['user_id' => Yii::$app->user->identity->id]);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public function actionIndex(){
    $searchModel = new CreateBookingsSearch();
    $session = yii::$app->session;
    $id = $session->get('user_id');
    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search($id);
    return $this->render('index',['searchModel'=>$searchModel, 'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider]);
 }
```

Comment: its kumari not kumar okk